# Get deeplink host url flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-deep-link

I'm having trouble getting the host url in `onGenerateRoute` callback.

```
onGenerateRoute: (routeSettings) {
  String url = routeSettings.name ?? "";
  log(url);
}
```

On cold start (when the app is closed and opened via url) `url` will be the full link (host + query params) - OK

When the app is in the background, `url` will contain only the query parameters of the url - not OK, I need the full link

I couldn't find any explanation why the `RouteSettings.name` returns different values for the same url when app is closed vs in the background.

I set the url in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```xml
<!-- Deep linking -->
<meta-data
    android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled"
    android:value="true" />

<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data
        android:host="example.com"
        android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

For example, if the link that I want to open the app is this: `https://example.com/something?param=value`

- when the app is closed, the `routeSettings.name` will be the whole link
- when the app is in the background, the `routeSettings.name` will be `/something?param=value`

EDIT:
Minimal reproducable example (modified the default counter app):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      onGenerateRoute: (routeSettings) {
        print("url:${routeSettings.name}");
      },
      title: 'Deeplink Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Deeplink test'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() => setState(() => _counter++);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text('You have pushed the button this many times:'),
            Text('$_counter', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Add the `<!-- Deep linking -->` section from above to AndroidManifest.xml, and also set the `launchMode` to `android:launchMode="singleTask"` so Android wont start a new instance of the app.